# Operador LIKE no funciona en mi app vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, tsql

Saludos a todos. Tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server que recupera datos con el operador like, pero no me resulta.

```
create procedure recupera_art 
@cadena char(40) 
select * from articulo where clave like '%'+ @cadena +'%'
```

cambie el procedimiento así:

```
create procedure recupera_art 
    @cadena char(40) 
    select * from articulo where clave like @cadena
```

y desde mi aplicación (vb.net) paso el parámetro de esta forma:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cadena", "%" + dts.gclave_art + "%")
```

pero me funciona a medias, es decir tengo las siguientes claves (AX101080,...,AX101095) , al querer hacer la consulta no me realiza nada al poner A, AX, AX1 ó AX10, tengo que poner AX101 para que me empiece a filtrar todos los datos de la tabla.

Lo que yo quiero es que al poner AX, A, AX1 o AX10 me pueda filtrar los datos, pienso que eso es posible.

Agradezco su colaboración para poder resolver el problema.

Comment: Podrias probar que solo haga el like de los de lado izquierdo de esta manera cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cadena", "%" + dts.gclave_art)

Comment: @RaulCacacho de hecho ya lo he probado, pero no me resulta nada, al igual que probé cambiando el **+** por **&** para concatenar

Comment: y de esta manera  select * from articulo where clave LIKE '%@SEARCH%'  y en el codigo cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cadena", "%" + dts.gclave_art + "%")

Comment: No me va, pero se me hace raro porque hice una prueba con esto desde la aplicación: `cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM vw_vendedor WHERE nombre_vendedor LIKE @cadena")`  `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text` y finalmente `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cadena", "%" + dtss.gnombre + "%")` y me va perfectamente

Comment: Te sugiero que pruebes modificar la definición del sp:  `@cadena char(40)` por `@cadena varchar(40)`y cualquier cosa nos dices.

Comment: Excelente, me ha funcionado de forma correcta. Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su colaboración, dejo la solución por si alguien le pasa.

```
create procedure recupera_art 
@cadena varchar(40) 
select * from articulo where clave like '%'+ @cadena +'%'
```

En la aplicación.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cadena", dts.gclave_art)
```

La explicación del problema es que un `char(40)` físicamente usa el espacio completo, esto puede verificarse con este ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @cadena CHAR(40)
SELECT @cadena  = 'BUSCA'
PRINT   '*' + @cadena + '*'
```

La salida:

```
*BUSCA                                   *
```

Al hacer `like '%'+ @cadena +'%'` cuando `@cadena` es un `CHAR` en realidad estamos haciendo:

```
like '%BUSCA                                   %'
```

Provocando que no podamos encontrar la información deseada.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu procedimiento funciona correctamente en SQL podrias intentar ejecutarlo  como si fuera t-sql

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC recupera_art 'texto para buscar'"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

De igual manera si en tu procedimiento ya lleva '%' no es necesario que lo agregues dentro de tu codigo en vb, de igual manera recomendaria que cambiaras ese char(40) por varchar(max)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el problema efectivamente se resolvió al cambiar **char(40)** por **varchar(40)**.